# RSpec + headless Chrome for front-end integration test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, google-chrome-headless

I'm trying to test a part of my Rails 5.1 app that makes use of Vue.js.
The issue I'm encountering is that, for example when generating a list, the Vue code looks like:

```
<div v-for="(amenity, idx) in amenities">
  <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" v-bind:id="amenity.text" v-model="checkedAmenities[idx]" :value="amenity.id">
    <label class="custom-control-label" v-bind="{ 'for': amenity.text }" >{{ amenity.text }}</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the actual HTML that this produces once evaluated looks like this:

```
<div>
  <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
    <input id="Air conditioning" class="custom-control-input" value="0" type="checkbox"> <label for="Air conditioning" class="custom-control-label">Air conditioning</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

I end up getting this error in my specs:

```
Capybara::ElementNotFound:
  Unable to find visible checkbox "Some amenity" that is not disabled
```

This is because the amenities are defined in the Vue component but are not output in the HTML until they are parsed by the JS interpreter I believe.

I am trying to test with Chrome Headless. I've created the following **chrome_driver.rb** file:

```
Capybara.register_driver(:headless_chrome) do |app|
  capabilities = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(
    chromeOptions: { args: %w[headless disable-gpu] }
  )

  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(
    app,
    browser: :chrome,
    desired_capabilities: capabilities
  )
end
```

and in my **rails_helper.rb**:

```
require 'selenium/webdriver'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  # ...
  Capybara.javascript_driver = :headless_chrome
end
```

my RSpec test looks something like this:

```
scenario 'successfully', js: true do
  # do some things here..

  check('Some amenity')
  click_button 'Next'
  click_link 'Create Listing'

  expect(page).to have_content 'Listing was created successfully!'
end
```

but as mentioned, the error I get is:

```
Capybara::ElementNotFound:
  Unable to find visible checkbox "Some amenity" that is not disabled
```

Any idea how I can get Chrome headless to parse the Vue.js code so that the amenities get populated on the frontend?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by the class names of the wrapping div, `custom-control custom-checkbox`, I'm pretty certain the issue here isn't that the fields aren't being populated correctly (you can use `save_and_open_screenshot` to verify that, or output `page.html`) but rather the actual html `<input type="checkbox" ...>` element is not actually visible on the page (as the error tells you). This was probably done in order to provide a fancy styling to the checkbox by showing images for the checked/unchecked states. To check the checkbox in that case you have a couple of options. The first option is to figure out what element the user actually needs to click to change the setting, and have Capybara do that. For instance

```
find(:label, 'Some amenity').click
```

The cleaner solution, when there is a correctly associated label element, is to tell the `check` method it's allowed to click the label if it needs to

```
check('Some amenity', allow_label_click: true)
```

If you want `check`, `uncheck`, and `choose` to always be allowed to click the associated label when a checkbox/radio button is hidden you can make that the default by setting

```
Capybara.automatic_label_click = true
```

Comment: Correct, I am using Bootstrap 4's `custom-checkbox` which does indeed seem to be creating an input checkbox which is not the actual `input[type="checkbox"]`. The latter probably gets selected via Javascript once the custom-checkbox is clicked. However, I still haven't been able to get it working with the methods you've described. I will keep trying to see if i need to select something else.

Comment: @DaniG2k Add the actual HTML that is produced for that control, rather than the vue template, to your question because it sounds like your `label` elements probably aren't actually correctly associated with the checkboxes

Comment: Ok I've added the actual generated HTML to the question for an example amenity

Comment: @DaniG2k And that's your issue -- HTML ids are not allowed to contain spaces, which means the `for` attribute isn't actually linking the label to the checkbox -- you want to use something other than the text for the `id` attribute of the input and the `for` attribute of the label

Comment: @DaniG2k Did this fix your issue?  If so, please don't forget to accept the answer so the question gets marked as answered.

Answer (score 0):

If your label contains a link it will be clicked and not the check box itself:

```
check('Some amenity', allow_label_click: true)
```

You can solve it this way:

```
check('Some amenity', visible: :hidden)
```