# RSpec: Vue.js code not compiling in Capybara tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, vue.js, webpack

I am trying to run some integration tests using RSpec & Capybara with Headless Chrome.

However, it seems the Vue.js code on the page doesn't get compiled, so the integration test fails to run properly.

I am using the following gems:

```
group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  gem 'pry'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.8'
  gem 'factory_bot_rails'
  gem 'faker', git: 'https://github.com/stympy/faker.git', branch: 'master'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'capybara-selenium'
  gem 'webdrivers'
end
```

My `rails_helper.rb` includes the lines:

```rb
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'capybara/rails'
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'selenium/webdriver'

# ...

Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome)
end

Capybara.register_driver :headless_chrome do |app|
  capabilities = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(
    chromeOptions: { args: %w[headless disable-gpu] }
  )

  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new app,
    browser: :chrome,
    desired_capabilities: capabilities
end

# Capybara.default_driver = :headless_chrome
# Capybara.javascript_driver = :headless_chrome

Capybara.default_driver = :chrome
Capybara.javascript_driver = :chrome
```

The output of webpacker info:

```
bundle exec rails webpacker:info                                  
Ruby: ruby 2.6.5p114 (2019-10-01 revision 67812) [x86_64-darwin19]
Rails: 6.0.1
Webpacker: 4.0.7
Node: v8.9.2
Yarn: 1.19.1

@rails/webpacker: 
myapp@ /Users/me/Documents/apps/myapp
└── @rails/webpacker@4.0.7 

Is bin/webpack present?: true
Is bin/webpack-dev-server present?: true
Is bin/yarn present?: true
```

But when I run the integration, instead of the Vue.js code executing as expected I am seeing it being output as text to the page, as such:

[image: Vue.js code being printed on the page instead of being executed]

I've also tried running

```
RAILS_ENV=test rails assets:precompile
```

before running the spec but that didn't seem to work either.

This is the spec file:

```rb
RSpec.feature 'Users can create invocies' do
  let(:user) { create(:user) }
  let(:address) { create(:address, user: user) }

  let(:client) { create(:client, user: user) }
  let!(:client_address) { create(:address, user: user, client: client) }

  before do
    login_as user
    visit new_invoice_path
  end

  context 'successfully' do
    it 'displays a success message on creation' do
      fill_in 'Invoice No.', with: rand(1..100)
      select address.full_address, from: 'invoice_personal_address'
      select client_address.full_address, from: 'invoice_client_address'

      fill_in 'Service name', with: 'Amazing web development'
      fill_in 'Service description', with: 'Web development for real pros.'

      fill_in 'Quantity', with: rand(1..10)
      fill_in 'Rate', with: rand(30.0..80.0)

      fill_in 'Date issued', with: Date.today
      fill_in 'Date due', with: 1.month.from_now

      click_button 'Create Invoice'

      expect(page).to have_content 'Invoice was successfully created.'
    end
  end
end
```

And my `./config/webpacker.yml`:

```
# Note: You must restart bin/webpack-dev-server for changes to take effect

default: &default
  source_path: app/javascript
  source_entry_path: packs
  public_root_path: public
  public_output_path: packs
  cache_path: tmp/cache/webpacker
  check_yarn_integrity: false
  webpack_compile_output: false

  # Additional paths webpack should lookup modules
  # ['app/assets', 'engine/foo/app/assets']
  resolved_paths: []

  # Reload manifest.json on all requests so we reload latest compiled packs
  cache_manifest: false

  # Extract and emit a css file
  extract_css: false

  static_assets_extensions:
    - .jpg
    - .jpeg
    - .png
    - .gif
    - .tiff
    - .ico
    - .svg
    - .eot
    - .otf
    - .ttf
    - .woff
    - .woff2

  extensions:
    - .vue
    - .mjs
    - .js
    - .sass
    - .scss
    - .css
    - .module.sass
    - .module.scss
    - .module.css
    - .png
    - .svg
    - .gif
    - .jpeg
    - .jpg

development:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  # Verifies that correct packages and versions are installed by inspecting package.json, yarn.lock, and node_modules
  check_yarn_integrity: true

  # Reference: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/
  dev_server:
    https: false
    host: localhost
    port: 3035
    public: localhost:3035
    hmr: false
    # Inline should be set to true if using HMR
    inline: true
    overlay: true
    compress: true
    disable_host_check: true
    use_local_ip: false
    quiet: false
    headers:
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    watch_options:
      ignored: '**/node_modules/**'


test:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  # Compile test packs to a separate directory
  public_output_path: packs-test

production:
  <<: *default

  # Production depends on precompilation of packs prior to booting for performance.
  compile: false

  # Extract and emit a css file
  extract_css: true

  # Cache manifest.json for performance
  cache_manifest: true
```

Any idea what I'm doing incorrectly?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Without your spec file, it's hard to figure out, if not impossible.

Comment: Spec added, but it won't help. I think webpacker is the problem. It doesn't compile anything in test.

Comment: https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/testing.html ?

Comment: I think that's unrelated. I'm not unit testing Vue code. I'm running an integration test with RSpec+Capybara which should run in a browser.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49609406/rspec-headless-chrome-for-front-end-integration-test?

Comment: Not sure if this is helpful, but https://github.com/johnmeehan/vuerspec

Comment: Haha yep I seem to have bad luck with RSpec + Capybara + Chrome headless + Vue.js code. My current issue seems unrelated to the one I'd posted back then. This form doesn't have check boxes. The values within the select dropdowns are actually being populated with raw Vue code. I suspect webpacker isn't compiling the JS assets before the test suite runs.

Comment: Care to post your webpacker.yml file?

Comment: @AlexMacArthur added! Hope it helps explain the problem cause I still haven't figured this one out :/ Thanks